# How to remove an element in reactjs by an attribute?

Tags: reactjs

I want to get unknown key attribute using known ID so that i may delete corresponding div.

I tried using `document.getElementById("a").getAttribute('key');` , but it isn't working. May be my concept is wrong.

```
class PostAdded extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super();
      this.deletepost = this.deletepost.bind(this);
    }

    deletepost() {
      let ab =document.getElementById("a").getAttribute('key');
      console.log(ab)
}

    render() {
            return (
              <div>
              { this.props.posts.map((post, i) =>
                <div id="a" key={`i-${post.title}`}>
                <span> <h3>{post.title}</h3><p>{post.post}</p></span>
                <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick={this.deletepost}/>
                </div>
              ) }        
            </div>
            )
        }    
}
export default PostAdded;
```

Comment: I don't see why you would be using `getAttribute` in a React app, but the syntax seems correct

Comment: We need more info here. Can you post the HTML or markup snippet that you are trying to target, please?

Comment: Please share your specific error from the Javascript console in your browser and please give us more context around your code. A simple "it isn't working" is not enough.

Comment: I updated question. See, @AidanLovelace

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to delete the div, that probably wouldn't end up working for you anyway because any state change would cause a re-render and it would appear again. Instead, you could keep track of your posts in state and then remove one of the posts from state in your `deletepost` method.

```
    class PostAdded extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super();
          this.state = {
            posts: props.posts
          }
          this.deletepost = this.deletepost.bind(this);
        }

        deletepost(index) {
          const newPosts = this.state.posts.splice(index)
          this.setState({posts: newPosts})
        }

        render() {
                return (
                  <div>
                  { this.state.posts.map((post, i) =>
                    <div id="a" key={`i-${post.title}`}>
                    <span> <h3>{post.title}</h3><p>{post.post}</p></span>
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick={() => this.deletepost(i)}/>
                    </div>
                  ) }        
                </div>
                )
            }    
    }
    export default PostAdded;
```